# Help with Sample Size Calculation for an infected species

Tags: statistics

A biologists are planning a study to estimate the proportion of an animal species that are infected a bacterial pathogen. He has come up with a way to obtain blood samples from a simple random sample of animals in the target population. He agrees in wanting an estimate of the percent infected that is accurate to within plus or minus four percentage points (or less), nineteen times out of twenty.

What sample size should he recommend for this study?

sqrt((0.5)(0.5)/n) = 0.04

n = 156

Why is this approach not correct?

Comment: Forgot about the $1.96$.

Comment: But the question did not specify 95% CI. I used 1.96 for my previous answer and it didn't work. n = 600 in that case.

Comment: It says in the text of the problem nineteen times out of twenty. That's $95\%$ confidence interval in news report language.

Comment: Oh i see. But 600 didn't work.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "600 didn't work"?

Comment: The answer wasn't accepted by an automated grading machine